# Can't ping from windows to linux laptop in different network

Tags: linux, networking, ip, redhat-enterprise-linux, mobile-hotspot

I have a  windows 10 laptop connected to mobile hotspot and my rhel 8 laptop connected to my wifi,
when i ping from my windows laptop to linux laptop getting request timed out.It might be a silly question but i am learning linux and trying to SSH to my RHEL 8 laptop.So wanted the ping to work.

Comment: As long as both machines are connected to the same wifi network that should be easy.

Comment: yes it works if they are in same network but i want them to be in different network and learn how it works and why it does not. thanks

Comment: How are the two networks connected together? (I'm going to guess they aren't?)

Comment: i added the ip of my linux system in ip setting of my windows laptop it did not work.
Any solution or hint would be great because i am trying to learn

Answer (score 0):

Typically quite difficult if the machines are on different networks.

- If the IP of the target machine is in the `10.*.*.*` or the `192.168.*.*` range, the target machine is in a private network. This is typically the case for anything connected to you home network (Wifi or wire).
- In a private network, members can initiate connections to other network participants. If one of these is a router (which is usually the case) they can also initiate connections to machines outside the network.
- Systems outside the network cannot initiate connections to systems inside (which is why your home systems have not yet been owned by hackers...). From the outside your private network looks like a single system that has the "public address" of the router.
- You can likely ask your router to do "port forwarding": a external connection request to some port (22 for SSH) is forwarded to some port of some machine inside the private network. However, do not do so unless your machine uses a rather long and non-trivial password (or key-based login), has a very strict SSH configuration  and is rate-limiting connection attempts. You can't imagine how fast strange people will come knowing at its door.

Comment: i was thinking about port forwarding but now i am little hesitant :( is it possible to port forward without router ?

Comment: If there is no router (or if the modem-router is in "pass-through" mode) you don't need to port-forward since your machine is directly on the internet. But your machine has better be seriously hardened, it's a dangerous world out there (on my servers, the first hacking attempts appear within 5 minutes). Better get a cheap VPS with a cloud provider ($5/month), so if anything happens you can just wipe it over, and nothing bad happens to your laptop.

Comment: thanks , i tried ssh tunneling and port forwarding , i could not get it to work.
cheers

Comment: any idea about request time out in ssh tunnelling

Comment: Pleas describe exactly everything you did by editing your question.